# How I can process the result of an SQL query by batch with CAMEL?

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-camel, endpoint, jbossfuse

I want to send the result of my sql query by batch example: if we have 5000 rows as a sql query result we process it 1000 by 1000.

This is the route:

```
<from uri="sql:select * from params?dataSource=moodleDB"/>
<split>
  <simple>body</simple>
  <setBody>
    <simple>My_URI_Params</simple>
  </setBody>
  <to uri="http://URI"/>
  <log message="Response: ${property.CamelSplitIndex} "/>
</split>
```

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an easy way to do it via the DSL, but You could easily implement your own splitting bean to manage this situation.

```
from("sql party")
    .split().method("springBeanName", "method")
        .to("some other process")
        .log("camel rocks!")
    .end()
    .to("Any process you want when camel is done");
```

Your bean method will look something like this (obviously logic for 1000 lines instead of each):

```
public String[] split(String body) {
    String[] split = body.split("\n");
    return split;
}
```